# Can you apply generalized binomial theorem on $(1+e^{i\theta})^n$ where $\theta\in\mathbb R$?

Tags: binomial-theorem

While solving a definite integral, I have done [this](https://qr.ae/prdm1x) myself i.e, expand $(1+e^{i\theta})^n$ for real $\theta$.

[image]

The generalized binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ requires that $|x|<1$.

I ended up with correct answer in that integral. However, when I look back, what bugs me is that $|e^{i\theta}| = 1$, so binomial theorem shouldn't be applicable. Can anyone help me clear my confusion?

Comment: The binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ does *not* require $|x| < 1$ if $n$ is a non-negative integer.

Comment: What is the generalized binomial theorem? As far as I can tell, it's an algebraic identity. The norm of $x$ should not come into play at all here.

Comment: Interesting $1/4$-fractional derivative. At any rate if $n$ is a natural number then there’s no problem. Since you use “$-t$”, presumably any old real, I would recommend doing a little “regularising”, ie evaluate the integral for $(1+e^{i\theta}e^{-\epsilon})^{-t}$, or something like that, and then take $\epsilon\to0^+$

Comment: @AndrewZhang They mean the power series for something like $(1+x)^{1/\pi}$.

Comment: @FShrike You may want to see the integral by visiting my Quora answer which I've linked in this post.

Comment: BTW, for why the negative sign in $-\ln\cos x$, it's because $\ln \cos x$ is negative for all real $x$.